# How do I build a placeholder object when an HTTP call fails with 404 with Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular 2 to make an HTTP request which returns JSON, which I am then using to populate the properties of an object. The URL changes based on a username that I pass to the function that calls the http.get method. Obviously, when I pass a username to the function that doesn't exist in the database, it throws a 404 error.

Here is the http call:

```
 getUser(un: string):Observable<TwitchUser> {
    return this.http.get('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + un, { headers: this.getHeaders() })
      .map(r=>{
        let body = r.json();
        var user:TwitchUser = {
          name: un,
          displayName: body.display_name,
          status: body.status,
          logo: body.logo,
          isOnline: false,
          url: body.url
        };
        return user;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

What I want to do is, when the 404 error is thrown, build a "placeholder" object for the missing user account.

Something like this:

```
var user:TwitchUser = {
  name: un,
  displayName: un,
  status: 'No active account found for this user!',
  logo: 'http://hotchillitri.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/empty-avatar.jpg',
  isOnline: false,
  url: ''
};
```

However, I don't know how to make this happen with Angular 2. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Update:

I tried method #1 in the answer below:

```
.catch((error: any):Observable<TwitchUser>  => {
        var user: TwitchUser = {
          name: un,
          displayName: un,
          status: 'No active account found for this user!',
          logo: 'http://hotchillitri.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/empty-avatar.jpg',
          isOnline: false,
          url: ''
        };
        return user;
      }
```

But I get this error on the first line:

```
Argument of type '(error: any) => TwitchUser' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<TwitchUser>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'TwitchUser' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
    Type 'TwitchUser' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<{}>'.
      Property 'length' is missing in type 'TwitchUser'.
```

I tried method #2 in the answer below:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    let userNames: string[] = this.service.getUsernames();
    for (var i = 0; i < userNames.length; i++) {
      this.service.getUser(userNames[i])
        .subscribe(u => {
          this.service.getUserIsOnline(u.name).subscribe(val => {
            u.isOnline = val;
            this.users[this.users.length] = u;
            if(this.users.length == userNames.length){
              this.changeMode(0);
            }

          });

        }
        , (error) => {
          console.log("an error occurred! Username is " + userNames[i])
        }
        , () => {
          console.log("inside the 'final' block. Username is " + userNames[i])
        }
        );
    }
  }
```

But I am unable to determine which username caused the issue because the catch and finally blocks only execute once (i = userNames.length when I log it).

Comment: Update: I tried doing a status check inside the .map to check for 404 and building the placeholder object in the "else" portion, but in the event of an error, it appears to skip the map and jump directly to the catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

Be sure you are importing "throw" in your service:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

without this, the code will compile, but it will not work correctly.

Also, try changing the return line in the error handler to:

```
return Observable.throw(user);
```

That will match your method's return type and then you can access the user on the component side with:

```
, (user) => {
//do something with user..
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can specify in your .catch() what you want to return either error message or "placeholder" object as you mentioned above.

```
.catch((error: any) => {
      // you can return error 
        return (Observable.throw(error.json())) 
      }
    })
```

or you can retrun placeholder object, it all depends on your requirement

```
.catch((error: any) => {
      // you can return error 
          var user:TwitchUser = {
          name: un,
          displayName: body.display_name,
          status: body.status,
          logo: body.logo,
          isOnline: false,
          url: body.url
          };
          return user;
      }
 })
```

And you can catch your error response in error block from where you are consuming your service

```
 .subscribe((result) => {
        console.log(result)
    }
        , (error) => {
            // you can catch error response in this block
            console.log(error)
        }
        , () => {
            //finally block, always executes
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will implement this tonight and report back.

Comment: I tried the methods your proposed and I updated the question with the results. I am still unable to create the "placeholder" object when an error is thrown.